# How can I wait between two reverse of UIView animation?

Tags: ios, uiviewanimation

I want to shake a price button. After each reversing, it should wait for some seconds.

```
 [UIView animateWithDuration:0.14f delay:0 options:(UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut) animations:^{
        self.priceButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(3));
        self.priceButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(-6));
        self.priceButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(3));
    } completion:nil];
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either have each of those rotations be in its own animateWithDuration block in the completion of each other, or you could put each of them in a selector and call:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(setRad:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:(either -6 or 3 here)] afterDelay:0.14f*(either 0 1 or 2)];
```

and then in the selector setRad, you set the transform in an animation block.